# Apache: python directory restriction

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Lets say I have directory with subdirectories where are projects stored.
How to lock Python script inside that subdirectory ? That it can not scan parent directories, read files, import etc. Is it possible with mod_wsgi ?

And how to disable any python functions ?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. Use mod_wsgi daemon mode and run the daemon process as a distinct user. Then lock down all your file permissions appropriately to deny access from that user. The second is that mod_wsgi daemon mode also supports a chroot option. Using a chroot is obviously a lot more complicated to set up however.

Comment: Because the subdirectories must have the same user, how to setup chroot ? I tried setting it up in daemon, but it does not take effect. When I run test.py, it can read directories all over the system.

Comment: Using chroot environments is a complicated topic that can never be answered in a Q&A site like this so I am not even going to attempt to do so. You really need to do some proper research into chroot environments yourself to understand what they can provide and then actually create some yourself so you know how they work. Only when you have mastered them should you then consider trying to use them for anything where security actually matters. Blindly trying to get something working without understanding them is a recipe for disaster.